# how to custom acts_as_taggable_on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags, acts-as-taggable-on

how to custom acts_as_taggable_on?

ive had tags,post_tags,posts(Model:Tag,PostTag,Post) in my database.

i do :gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 2.2.2' in Gemfile.

when generate migration,i found that it has generated default tables(tags,tagger,tagging).

how to custom the default option to adapt my Model?

Answer (score 3):

All tags are stored in *ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag(:id, :name)* model and get accessed through *ActsAsTaggableOn::Taggable(:id, :tag_id, :taggable_type, :taggable_id, :context etc)* model.

If you want to switch to acts-as-taggable and not to lose your previously added tags you should  create a migration or rake task after creating acts-as-taggable-on default tables.

Like this:

```
# In your model
acts_as_taggable_on :post_tags

# Rake task
require 'acts-as-taggable-on'

task :move_tags => [:environment] do
  @posts = Post.all
  Post.transaction do
    Tag.transaction do
      @posts.each do |p|
        if p.tags.any?
          p.update_attributes post_tag_list: p.tags.map(&:name)
          p.tags.map(&:destroy)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

# Now, if all is ok, you can drop both old tags and join table and remove associasions from your Post model.
```

I didn't test this snippet but I've successfully done similar thing before.